# Boost Python: creating one module (.so) out of multiple .cpp files

Tags: python, c++, boost

I started writing (in C++) some module I want to be callable inside Python code. I use Boost Python for this purpose. As my code will be growing, I decided to divide it into several .cpp files. Now, I have something like that:
**foo.cpp**

```
#include "Bar.hpp"
#include "Baz.hpp"
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo){

    def("help", help);

    class_<Bar>("Bar", init<bp::list>())
    .def("add", &Bar::add)
    .def("show", &Bar::show);


}
```

**Bar.cpp**

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Baz.hpp"

namespace bp=boost::python;


class Bar{
    private:
        std::vector<std::string> items; 

    public:
        Bar(bp::list list):items(toCppVector(list)){}
        ~Bar(){}
        void add(std::string x){
            numbers.push_back(x);
        }
        bp::list show(){
            return toPythonList(items);
        }           
};
```

**Bar.hpp**

```
#ifndef Bar_hpp
#define Bar_hpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
namespace bp=boost::python;

class Bar{
    private:
        std::vector<std::string> items; 

    public:
        Bar(bp::list list);
        ~Bar();
        void add(std::string x);
        bp::list show();        
};

#endif
```

**Baz.cpp**

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace bp=boost::python;


//C++ vector to Python list
template <class T>
bp::list toPythonList(std::vector<T> vector) {
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator iter;
    bp::list list;
    for (iter = vector.begin(); iter != vector.end(); ++iter) {
        list.append(*iter);
    }
    return list;
}

//Python list to C++ int vector
std::vector<int> toCppVectorInt(bp::list list){
    std::vector<int> vector;
    for (int i=0;i !=bp::len(list) ;i++){
        vector.push_back(bp::extract<int>((list)[i]));
    }
    return vector;
}

//Python list to C++ string vector
std::vector<std::string> toCppVectorStr(bp::list list){
    std::vector<std::string> vector;
    for (int i=0;i !=bp::len(list) ;i++){
        vector.push_back(bp::extract<std::string>((list)[i]));
    }
    return vector;
}

std::string help(){
    return "some help information ";    

}
```

**Baz.hpp**

```
#ifndef Baz_hpp
#define Baz_hpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace bp=boost::python;
template <class T>
bp::list toPythonList(std::vector<T> vector);
//Python list to C++ int vector
std::vector<int> toCppVectorInt(bp::list list);
//Python list to C++ string vector
std::vector<std::string> toCppVectorStr(bp::list list);
std::string help();

#endif
```

and my **setup.py** file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(name="PackageName", ext_modules=[Extension("foo",["foo.cpp"],
        libraries = ["boost_python"])
    ])
```

Compilating it with:

```
python setup.py build
```

I obtain file foo.so (compilation terminates without errors). Unfortunatelly, it doesn't work. When I'm trying to use it in Python interpreter, I receive this effect:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./foo.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3NNB3addESs
>>>
```

What should I correct in my code?

Comment: Is this code working now?

Comment: Why you redefine classes in your cpp files? `Bar.cpp` should contain: `void Bar::add(std::string x){
            numbers.push_back(x);
        }`, and so on. You have two `Bar` classes, and methods of `Bar` from `Bar.hpp` (`add()`, `show()`) are not implemented - thus, undefined symbol. Bhrrr! It stems from the fact that `Bar.cpp` does not include `Bar.hpp`.

Comment: Ok, I see. Simple mistakes.